# playing multiple songs using mediaplayer class(for loop)

Tags: android

```
  mpintro= new MediaPlayer();
                for(int i=2;i<results.size();i++){
                    if(results.get(i).equals(emotion[position])){
                        try {
                            mpintro.setDataSource(retmus.get(i));
                            mpintro.start();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
```

I want to play a complete list of songs using mediaplayer class which can be indexed through for loop.It doesnt show any error.but it doesnt play also.

Comment: Do you want play multiple music at same time ?

Comment: Do you want play music one by one?